# Are there any public agencies which are currently streaming real-time video data?

Tags: releasing-data, internet, computing, security, video

I'm engaged in a discussion with the network security department at a public agency with the goal of making their live video data publicly available on the Internet; currently the data never leaves their private network. Most if not all of the cameras support RTSP (Real Time Streaming Protocol).

Security is obviously a paramount concern and beyond that it would be ideal to find a solution which allows for fine-grained access management and integration with common directory services (e.g. LDAP and Active Directory) for authentication and authorization.

I have some basic understanding of what goes into architecting a solution to this kind of problem, but not enough to make specific recommendations with a high degree of confidence. I was hoping to find some examples of other public agencies which have successfully carried out this sort of project so that we might be able to model our solution on something that's already been shown to work.

One particular software package that jumped out at me was [DataTurbine](http://dataturbine.org/). Are there other, similar tools out there? Are there any cities or other public agencies which are using them to stream live video data over the internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there are (U.S.) public agencies that are currently (2017-03-07) streaming real-time video data. I'm not aware of a list of them (would LOVE it, if one such exists), but here's one:

[Live Video Stream - NOAA Ship Okeanos Explorer](http://oceanexplorer.noaa.gov/okeanos/media/exstream/exstream.html)

I'm not familiar with DataTurbine, nor aware of similar tools, but that's not to say they don't exist.
Seattle has been quite proactive regarding publishing their Police Department's body cameras data; while not streaming/real-time, they have been blazing the trail for other agencies/departments in this arena. Particularly around data storage, as well as privacy issues. One (amazing) citizen that was actively submitting FOIA requests for their data was actually hired by them to set up/run this project. Contacting the City of Seattle and/or Seattle Police Department is definitely worth your time here.

Comment: I was hoping for something closer to an out-of-the-box solution that I could use or an architecture that I could imitate, but I guess it may be the case that no such response is forthcoming. Done!

Comment: I was going to give the same answer ;-) Note though, that they only do several series of dives a year. They were at Samoa in the second half of Feb 2017, they are currently near Tokelau. And the actual live stream is only during the dive (which starts somewhere around 22:00 UTC), the rest are edits/replays.